# responsive positioning of buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i am using a `Dialog` to show user some options. i have inflated a `xml` which content some button. in landscape mode the buttons are showing like this:[image: land_dialog]

in portrait mode buttons are showing in a line. but as the screen cannot hold all the buttons, some buttons are not showing. i want the buttons in portrait mode like this:[image: portrait_dialog]

that means responsive. **but how can i do that?** my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/jinish" >

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/sound2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sound_xml"/>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/review2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/review_xml"/>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/instraction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/instraction_xml"/>            

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/solve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/solve_xml"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>  

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/reset_xml"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my java code:

```
private LinearLayout options_layout;
private Dialog options_show;

options_layout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.puzzle_options, null);

options_show = new Dialog(this);
options_show.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
options_show.setContentView(options_layout);
options_show.setCancelable(true);
options_show.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
options_show.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

options_show.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use a `GridView`, and set its columns to a dimen: `android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"`
- Add to your dimensions declarations (values/dimens.xml for example): `<integer name="num_columns">3</integer>`
- Add another dimensions file with the orientation set to landscape (values-land/dimens.xml for example): `<integer name="num_columns">6</integer>`

Now, depending on the device orientation, Android will pick the value 3 or 6 for the number of columns.

You will need to create a basic adapter to bind data to the `GridView`.